# erect perimeter in spritekit xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode6, sprite-kit, cmmotionmanager

I am working on a simple game using sprite kit.
I have three sprites moving around the screen.
I have the sprites move by using

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.005f;

self.motionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.motionQueue.name = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] stringByAppendingString:@".motion"];

self.updatePosition = NO;
[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:self.motionQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
        [formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];
        {
            numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:motion.gravity.x / 20.0 *200]];
            numberStringy = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:motion.gravity.y / 20.0 *200]];
            n = [numberString intValue];
  y = [numberStringy intValue];
 }
        self.gravity = motion.gravity;
        self.updatePosition = YES;
    }
}];

[self startDisplayLink];
- (void)startDisplayLink
{
self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
[self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

 - (void)stopDisplayLink
{
[self.displayLink invalidate];
self.displayLink = nil;
 }

- (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
@synchronized(self) {
    if (!self.updatePosition)
        return;

    self.sprite1.position = CGPointMake(self.sprite1.position.x + (n*.99), self.sprite1.position.y + (y*.99));
    self.sprite2.position = CGPointMake(self.sprite2.position.x + (n*.98), self.sprite2.position.y +(y*.98));
    self.sprite3.position = CGPointMake(self.sprite3.position.x + n, self.sprite3.position.y + y);
}
```

I have enable collision detection on the sprites (1,2,3) like this

```
 sprite1.physicsBody =
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:(ball1.size.width/2)];
sprite1.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
sprite1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
sprite1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;
sprite1.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
```

HERE IS THE NEW CODE FOR EDGE LOOP

CGRect border= CGRectInset (self.frame,325,133);

self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:border];

How do I place a perimeter around this so that when the sprites come into contact with it they go no further even if a second sprite collides with the sprite already stopped at the edge.  I do not want the edge of the screen to be the perimeter but one I define.

Right now I have the sprites stopping by using

```
if (sprite1.position.x <=340) {
        sprite1.position = CGPointMake(340, sprite1.position.y);
}
```

for every sprite and every edge

This works to stop the sprite when it reaches the edge but when another sprite collides with it the sprite at the edge goes beyond the edge.

isn't there a way to define a perimeter that no matter what no sprite can go outside of it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can create an edge loop around the scene with [bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:) with `view.frame` as the rect. You can shrink/grow the rect with [CGRectInset](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectInset).

Comment: I did this using  the added code to my original post but if I remove the code stopping the sprite when it reaches the edge sprite! will stop at the edge but when sprite2 hits it sprite1 goes beyond the edgeloop and disappears.  Do I need to do more to set up edgeloop.  I also made each sprite to have 0 mass thinking then it wouldn't effect the other sprites when they collide but they still move each other.

Comment: You need to move each sprite by applying a force or impulse to its physics body or by setting the body's velocity property. The sprites will not be a part of the physics simulation if you move them by setting their positions over time with `sprite.position = CGPoint...`.

Comment: See this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html